# Model doesn't update with selected value- AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm working on creating a table from a JSON Object. The fiddle for my work is at - https://jsfiddle.net/sukto1e0/4/

Here is my markup -

```
<form ng-controller="RelCon as Rel">
  <div id="{{'rel' + $index}}" ng-repeat="relation in relations">
    <p>{{relation.MappingName}}</p>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-hover src-tgt-table">
        <thead>
          <tr id="row0">
            <th>#</th>
            <th>{{relation.TargetName}}</th>
            <th>{{relation.SourceName}}</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="(key,value) in relation.columnMapping">
          <tr id="{{'row' + ($index + 1)}}">
            <th scope="row">{{$index + 1}}</th>
            <td>
              {{key}}
            </td>
            <td>
              <select ng-model="value" ng-options="j as j for (i,j) in relation.columnMapping">

              </select>
            </td>
            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok edit hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="output()">
      print
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

and here is the controller -

```
    var app = angular.module('test', []);

    app.controller('RelCon', function($scope) {
      $scope.relations = [{
        "SourceName": "CUSTOMER_DATA",
        "MappingName": "m_Load_STAGING",
        "TargetName": "CUSTOMER_DATA_STG",
        "columnMapping": {
          "CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.STATE": "CUSTOMER_DATA.STATE",
          "CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.UPDATE_TIME": "CUSTOMER_DATA.NAME",
          "CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.PHONE": "CUSTOMER_DATA.PHONE",
          "CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.ADDRESS": "CUSTOMER_DATA.ADDRESS",
          "CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.NAME": "CUSTOMER_DATA.NAME",
          "CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.ZIP": "CUSTOMER_DATA.ZIP",
          "CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.SSN": "CUSTOMER_DATA.SSN",
          "CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.SOURCE_SYSTEM": "CUSTOMER_DATA.ADDRESS",
          "CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.EMAIL": "CUSTOMER_DATA.EMAIL",
          "CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.CUSTOMERID": "CUSTOMER_DATA.CUSTOMERID",
          "CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.CITY": "CUSTOMER_DATA.CITY"
        }
      }];
      $scope.output = function() {
        console.log($scope.relations);
      };
    });
```

In the second column I need to have the model update when the value selected in the dropdowns is changed. I got the dropdown populated correctly with the options and set to the default value as in the JSON.

The problem is when I change the selected value for any one of the dropdown and click the button for console print, I don't see the updated value.

Please guide me on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you want to update only the second column with respect to dropdown value or did you want have updated value in the console too?

Comment: I need the model to be updated when I do a change in any of the dropdown's. From what I understand, ng-model defines a two way data binding. So I don't understand why changing the value in the dropdowns isn't affecting the model (`$scope.relations`)

Comment: I am looking at your issue and I noticed something unrelated. By having the ng-repeat on the <tbody>, you are actually creating multiple <tbody>'s.  If you would put it on the <tr>, it will create multiple table rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a key-value pair. This will pass a string to your ng-model with the result that it won't create two way binding. I've updated your jsfiddle.

Miško famous qoute:

> "..if you use ng-model there has to be a dot somewhere. If you don't
>   have a dot, you're doing it wrong.."

I have updated your HTML to:

```
<tbody >
  <tr ng-repeat="mapping in relation.columnMapping" id="{{'row' + ($index + 1)}}">
    <th scope="row">{{$index + 1}}</th>
    <td>
      {{mapping.id}}
    </td>
    <td>
      <select ng-model="mapping.value" ng-options="j.value as j.value for (i,j) in relation.columnMapping">

      </select>
    </td>
    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok edit hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

And I have updated your model to:

```
  $scope.relations = [{
    "SourceName": "CUSTOMER_DATA",
    "MappingName": "m_Load_STAGING",
    "TargetName": "CUSTOMER_DATA_STG",
    "columnMapping": [
      {id:"CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.STATE",value:"CUSTOMER_DATA.STATE"},
      {id:"CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.UPDATE_TIME",value:"CUSTOMER_DATA.NAME"},
      {id:"CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.PHONE",value: "CUSTOMER_DATA.PHONE"},
      {id:"CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.ADDRESS",value: "CUSTOMER_DATA.ADDRESS"},
      {id:"CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.NAME",value: "CUSTOMER_DATA.NAME"},
      {id:"CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.ZIP",value: "CUSTOMER_DATA.ZIP"},
      {id:"CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.SSN",value: "CUSTOMER_DATA.SSN"},
      {id:"CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.SOURCE_SYSTEM",value: "CUSTOMER_DATA.ADDRESS"},
      {id:"CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.EMAIL",value: "CUSTOMER_DATA.EMAIL"},
      {id:"CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.CUSTOMERID",value: "CUSTOMER_DATA.CUSTOMERID"},
      {id:"CUSTOMER_DATA_STG.CITY",value: "CUSTOMER_DATA.CITY"}
    ]
  }];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/039wfm6w/1/

Comment: Thanks- Noted! I updated my model further from your suggestion. The problem with the suggested model is that if you selected one value for all the dropdowns, eventually all the options in the array get replaced. I will post an edit to this answer with my modification and set this as the answer in a bit